# Query to return number

Tags: php, sql

```
$total_rows = myDB::query("Select count(id) from video");
while ($total = myDB::fetchAssoc($total_rows)) {
   $result["total"]=$total;
}
```

this returns to me

```
total:{count(id): "3"}
       count(id):"3"
```

How can I make it possible to return only total:3 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `myDB`? What does it contains?

Comment: @Syscall that's a class created by sb else

Comment: Does `'Select count(id) as total from video'` work?

Comment: print only `$total = myDB::fetchAssoc($total_rows)`, remove while loop.

Comment: `Select count(id) as total from video`

Comment: The query will only return one row, a count only ever returns one row, so your loop is unnecessary

Comment: $total_rows = myDB::fetchAssoc("Select count(id) from video");
            $total = myDB::fetchAssoc("Select count(id) from video");
                $result["total"]=$total; Returns null

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay it does the job but now it overrides my previous array ,I have to return $result and add the total to it

Comment: `$result["total"]=$total['total];`

Comment: Thanks guys it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result["total"]=$total['total];
```